# Visitors (Read) cannot see some web parts

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

**Edit**

I found out that the profile.js and aboutcarousel.js files are referenced in the master page:

```
    <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="Themable/corev15.css" runat="server" />
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="/SiteAssets/css/ITDcore.css" runat="server" after="corev15.css"/>
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" runat="server" after="corev15.css"/>

<!-- Custom Scripts -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">//<![CDATA[//]]></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/js/Profile.js">//<![CDATA[//]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/js/AboutCarousel.js">//<![CDATA[//]]>
</script>
<!-- End Custom Scripts -->
```

These 2 js files are the ones the Visitors cannot see.  I modified the Visitors permission to **Contribute** and they were able to see both displays.  I changed back to **Read** and the profile and carousel disappeared again.

I also found out that if I add either one of the following **List Permissions** to default **Read**, user can see the displays:

- Add Items
- Delete Items
- Edit Items

The weird part is during testing, its very inconsistent which one gives the right permission. Sometimes **Add Items** work, sometime it doesn't while **Edit Items** would, or vice versa. **BUT**, Visitors shouldn't have any of these List Permissions. Is the custom script added incorrectly in the master page? It works with at least contribute permission...

[image]

**Work around:**

I gave visitors `Contribute` permission in the **Master Page Gallery** -- not sure if this is the best practice...

---

I have the following security groups in sharepoint:

- Members (contribute)
- Owners (full control)
- Visitors (read)

However, visitors cannot see some of the web parts (script editor). I checked and user in **Visitors** group can access the Site Assets, Site Pages, and Photo Gallery which are referenced on the script.

But when I added the test account to the **Members** group - test account was able to see the web parts. Target audience for the web part is blank.

Other tests and results:

- Changed **Visitors** permission from read to View Only, Contribute, or Full Control - same results, cannot see the same web parts.
- Created another security group - still same result.
- Gave permission to the test account individually (not part of Members, Owners, Visitors) - test account got an access denied message after browser refresh.
- Same results in IE, Edge, and Chrome

Any ideas what could be causing this odd behavior?

Comment: Is this script placed in HTML code for visitors? What are check in/check out statuses for script and page?

Comment: Check if the js files are checked in. Check if the page itself is checked in, check if the webpart is actually on the page for all users and not on a personal view (Append ?contents=1 to the page URL) Edit: since you granted full control I guess the Webpart is on a personal view...

Comment: It sounds similar to an issue I have experienced.  You could try checking whether users have access to the Style Library.

Comment: @AlexZh, there are no check in/check out.  The codes are all in Site Assets, which has inherited permission.

Comment: @HeikoHatzfeld_MSFT, the Script Editor only has `<div id="cardplaceholder"></div>~ in it, which is part of the code in CEWP (as a txt file) which is located in Site Assets.

Comment: @Tally, I also checked Style Library and it too has inherited permission.  Test account can even click the .js file and view on browser.

Comment: @TamrasMerin, I meant that your web parts suppose placing some code to the resulting html of the page. Are that script links or code snippets really in the code for visitors (which means web parts are working correctly)?

Comment: @AlexZh, Thanks! one of the .js files links are located in another site collection so I gave permission to that site. But visitors still can't see the profile and carousel web parts.  Please see my initial post, I added more info I recently discovered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be caused by having the master page not published as a Major version. To be sure check out/in and then publish as a major version. If it is HTML design file associated you should perform the actions on it.

And I agree that granting contribute to the master page gallery is not a good practice.

Comment: Thank you James.  It worked! I reverted the permission settings for Master Page Gallery.